# Display specific the selected product attribute on the WooCommerce variation price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I am trying to display the selected product attributes on the product single page after the .

I found many codes, that are even working, but all of these codes return a list of all available attributes.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'display_attribute', 5 );
function display_attribute(){
    global $product;
    $output = array();
    if( $verpackung = $product->get_attribute('pa_verpackung') ){
        echo $verpackung;
        $output[] = $verpackung;
    }
}
```

It's a variable product and I would like to show the size of the package, which is an attribute. For example: € 39,- for a box of 300g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will display after the selected variation price (on variable products) the corresponding packaging type like for example: *"€ 39,- for a box of 300g"*…

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'set_packaging_type_after_variation_price', 10, 3 );
function set_packaging_type_after_variation_price( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $targeted_taxonomy  = 'pa_verpackung'; // <== Define here the product attribute taxonomy

    // Loop through variation attributes
    foreach( $data['attributes'] as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ) {
        $attribute_taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $variation_attribute ); // Get product attribute the taxonomy

        // For matching variation attribute …
        if ( $attribute_taxonomy == $targeted_taxonomy ){
            $verpackung  = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $attribute_taxonomy )->name; // Get the term name
            $verpackung = ' <span class="verpackung">'. __('für eine '). $verpackung .'</span></span>';
            // Set the "packaging" after the selected viariation price
            $data['price_html'] = str_replace( '</span></span>', '</span>' . $verpackung, $data['price_html'] );
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.